# Sql Query problems with Case, Replicate and Trim functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, trim, replicate

I have some problems in my SQL queries.  The table name is **debitorders** which consists of the following columns:

1. firstname *(varchar(50),null)*
2. surname *(varchar(50),null)*
3. accountnumber *(varchar(50),null*)
4. accounttype *(varchar(50),null)*
5. bankname *(varchar(50),null)*
6. branch *(varchar(50),null)*
7. amount *(varchar(50),null)*
8. date *(date, null)*

This is our query so far:

```
SET @BankName = 'ABSA'
--SET @BankName = 'First National Bank'
SET @QueryResultA = (SELECT CASE @BankName 
                     WHEN 'ABSA' THEN 'ABSA            0040000146162'
                     WHEN 'First National Bank' THEN 'First National B0020000045603'
                     END)
--PRINT @QueryResultA
SET @Amount = (SELECT amount FROM debitorders)
SELECT
       left(LTRIM(RTRIM(firstname)),1) + '' + CONVERT (varchar(15),LTRIM(RTRIM(surname)),1),
       (SELECT left(cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(accountnumber)) as varchar(14))+replicate(' ',14),14) ),
       CASE accounttype 
         WHEN 'cheque' 
            THEN left(cast('CH' as varchar(3))+replicate(' ',3),3) 
         WHEN 'savings' 
            THEN left(cast('SAV' as varchar(3))+replicate(' ',3),3)
         WHEN 'credit card' 
            THEN left(cast('CC' as varchar(3))+replicate(' ',3),3)
         WHEN 'other' 
            THEN left(cast('OTH' as varchar(3))+replicate(' ',3),3)
      END, 
      left(cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(branch)) as varchar(10))+replicate(' ',10),10),   
      REPLICATE('0', 7 - DATALENGTH (REPLACE(amount,'.',''))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(amount,'.',''))),
      REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, date,103),'/','') AS DebitDate
      --REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 104) AS [DD.YYYY.MM]),'.',''
FROM debitorders
WHERE bankname = @BankName
```

The result should be:

1. firstname (pad side:n/a, Length:1)
2. surname (pad side:right, Length:15)
3. accountnumber (pad side:right, Length:14)
4. accounttype (pad side:right, Length:3)
5. branch (pad side:right, Length:10)
6. amount (pad side:left, Length:7)
7. date (pad side:n/a, Length:8, setting format to ddyyyymm)

Why aren't the columns recognized?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are trying to do. Typically when using `VARCHAR` datatype it is done to only store actual values not extra spaces. If you want to store spaces than you should consider `CHAR` datatype. Also can you add actual error message from SSMS. and please list your SQL Server version.

Comment: What is supposed to happen is for example surname, get the surname and add the spaces to the right of the surname so that the length of all, surname and empty spaces, is 15. 
Error message is this :Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid object name 'debitorders'.
Sql Server version is 2012

Comment: Your code has some strange things going on. You have a QueryResultsA variable that is set but not used. Then you set a variable from debitorders. But that query has no where clause and no aggregate which means it will get the value from the last row returned. Since you have no order by you don't even know which row it is. However, you don't use that variable anyway so not sure what the point of it is.

Comment: When you say the columns aren't recognized are you talking about when you run the query or is it that you just created the table and they are underlined with red squiggles? I suspect that is the case. You just need to refresh the local cache (ctrl + shift + r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your query against the correct database? Where was your debitorders table created?

I would say to first check that you're not running your query against the master database.

This link has a bit more information: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/31/sql-server-error-fix-msg-208-invalid-object-name-dbo-backupset-invalid-object-name-dbo-backupfile/

Comment: I can't believe it. Yes we were running it on the master! i feel really stupid now xD  thank you! it runs but i still get an error saying that Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. and for some reason when save is as a txt file there are so many spaces after the amount it self. could it be that its actualy taking the amount and multiplying it by 7 instead of setting the length of the amount to 7?

Comment: No problem, that still happens to me from time to time. I think that has to do with your 'SET @Amount = (SELECT amount FROM debitorders)' which would return multiple values and then attempt to set it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables:

```
DECLARE @BankName VARCHAR(50) = 'ABSA';
```

You're also trying to set multiple records in your @Amount variable. Do you need an aggregate here?

Comment: Richard Nixion, no I don't, there are no calculations supposed to be done here. Its only supposed to bring back the amount that is in debitorders and have the amount to length of 7, take away the '.' and add zeros.